# How can I translate this loop into a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to convert this loop into a for loop, but I can't get it to work, it's in C.

```
while(args[argCounter]){
        if(!strcmp(args[argCounter], "|")){
            args[argCounter] = NULL;
            cmdbegin[child] = argCounter + 1;
            child++;
        }
        argCounter++;
}
```

Comment: Just look at how a `for` loop works: `for( initial_condition; condition_to_keep_looping; what_to_do_after_each_iteration)`. Here, think about `argCounter`. You must have an initial value for it, so you'd set that in your initial condition. What do you do at the end of each iteration? You increment `argCounter`. And under what condition do you keep looping?

Comment: Well... `for (int argCounter = 0; args[argCounter]; ++argCounter) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would translate it as follows:

```
for (int argCounter = 0 ; args[argCounter] ; argCounter++){
    if(!strcmp(args[argCounter], "|")){
        args[argCounter] = NULL;
        cmdbegin[child++] = argCounter + 1;
    }
}
```

I added declaration and initialization of `argCounter` which you did not show. The conversion was very much mechanical:

- `argCounter++` moved to the third "compartment" of the `for` loop header,
- I moved `child++` into the assignment to shorten the code somewhat; this is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
char **tmp = args + argCounter;
for(;*tmp;tmp++)
{
    ++argcounter;
    if (!strcmp(*tmp, "|")) {
    *tmp = NULL;
    cmdbegin[child++] = argCounter;
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that your code sample, while incredibly beautiful (so much that I upvoted it), doesn't do exactly as the OP wanted. argCounter should be incremented even without entering the if. You could put it in the rightmost part of the for using a comparison (at a cost in performance) or simply put the increment before the if. ;) 

Still enjoyed reading your answer, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

The initial value of `argCounter` is not specified in your code. Here is a conversion:

```
for (; args[argCounter]; argCounter++) {
    if (!strcmp(args[argCounter], "|")) {
        args[argCounter] = NULL;
        cmdbegin[child] = argCounter + 1;
        child++;
    }
}
```

If the loop starts at `0` and you want to make `argCounter` local to the `for` loop, here is a C99 version:

```
for (int argCounter = 0; args[argCounter]; argCounter++) {
    if (!strcmp(args[argCounter], "|")) {
        args[argCounter] = NULL;
        cmdbegin[child] = argCounter + 1;
        child++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Arturo: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score and upvote the ones you want when you get enough reputation.